# past participle indicating time

Tags: past-participles, adverbial-phrases

> And as for staying tea, I can't hear of it; for there's this dairymaid, now she knows she's to be married, **turned** Michaelmas, she'd as lief pour the new milk into the pig-trough as into the pans.
> (http://www.literaturepage.com/read/silas-marner-158.html)

Could you explain the use of "turned." I think it should be "When it **turns** Michaelmas."

Comment: +1, that's a really interesting usage! Your interpretation seems correct: "turned" in that usage looks like it should be equivalent in meaning to "when it turns."  It reminds me of the similar (but much more common expression) ***come** [a certain day]* which means "when [a certain day] has come."

Comment: "Come Tuesday, someone should have answered your question" :)

Comment: This is highly irregular English. I'm quite surprised something this odd sounding is only 160-ish years old. It's so hard for me to understand I'd expect it to be at least 500 years old. It's not worth learning English from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language of many of the characters in this book is difficult, because they speak in a dialect which is not entirely real (it is a fictionalized Yorkshire / Northern English).

What the speaker means here is:  "Now that the dairymaid knows that she's going to be married by Michaelmas, she's as likely to pour the new milk in the pig trough as into the pans."

Michaelmas is is a Christian holiday celebrated in September.   The dairy maid is excited about her marriage and the speaker expects her to not perform well at her duties because she is distracted by her excitement.  She might, for example, mistakenly feed the fresh milk to the pigs instead of saving it for the household.

This is not standard English speech you will hear in modern SAE or RP.

Comment: Thanks.  May I ask what is SAE？ I'm not sure if it is Standard American English,  because I can't find a related definition in the dictionary.

Comment: Yes, Standard American English (SAE).   Not to be confused with Southern American English (SAE).  =/   (Some people also use General American English to avoid that confusion - the point is to acknowledge that there are other dialects of AE where we might have made a statement not evaluated in relation to each of them.)

Comment: Actually, Silas Marner has left Northern England and settled in the Midlands (where George Eliot herself grew up, so the speech patterns are probably authentic).

Comment: @KateBunting by "authentic",  do you mean it is  accepted and used in the modern English speaking world?

Comment: No - BadZen claimed that the dialect was 'not entirely real', but as 'George Eliot' grew up in Warwickshire, presumably the speech patterns resemble those she heard in real life. _Turned Michaelmas_ would not be used today but, as Quack E. Duck says, _come Michaelmas_ might be.

Comment: @KateBunting I think that the number of British people who know what Michaelmas is, let alone use it in conversation, must be very small. Likewise for 'come' before a date or time.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Well, dammit, _come Christmas_ then! The meaning of _Michaelmas_ isn't relevant to the meaning of _turned [date]_.

Comment: @KateBunting - it puts me in mind of Tom Forrest on The Archers saying that something-or-other would happen 'come Lady Day'. That ages me, I daresay.

Comment: Also compare "gone" in British English:  "Has it already **gone midnight**?."

Comment: The short form most commonly used on this site for American English is "AmE" in contrast with "BrE" for the other side of the pond. I mention this purely FYI, without any recommendation or endorsement attached.